What is the purpose of Personal References in a scholarship application form?
I am applying for an international scholarship in Switzerland. I have done similar applications in the past, where it is rather common for the awarding institution to request Academic references. However, in the current program that I am applying for, in the "References" section, besides the Academic References, I am asked (but not obliged) to provide personal references about whether "I already have contacts in the country or with citizens of the country" that I am applying for. I can select "No", and leave the form blank, or I can provide select "Yes" and name contacts.
I am trying to understand the purpose of such a questions, and what is the right way to answer it in a way that will help the application and not harm it. What is the right strategy here?
Could it be that they are asking such a question to see if the applicant would abuse the program for other means?

It could also be the opposite: if you have a functioning social net or at the very least a few contacts that can possibly help you get started, it might increase the chances of success for your studies. But then again, the Swiss tend to be kind of xenophobic, so you might be right.

“Personal references” oppose “academic references”: the latter should discuss your academic qualifications while presumably the former discuss non-academic aspects of your application.
Now obviously here the credibility of the source is important and for a non-academic reference it could be difficult to assess so this could be the reason they are asking if you know Swiss citizens as these would presumably be able to write something with proper context. I don’t see anything nefarious in this.
